# Trouble with getting padded 0's using printf

Tags: linux, bash, printf

When I enter the following script into linux bash I don't get the expected result:

(Script)

```
branch_line_number=01A
val=$(echo "obase=16; ibase=16; $branch_line_number + 1" | bc -l)
sum=$(printf "%03s" $val)
echo "check 6 val = $val : sum = $sum"
```

(Result)

```
check 6 val = 1B : sum =  1B
```

(Note: There is a space where there should be a zero in "sum")

I have tried using the following:

```
branch_line_number=01A
val=$(echo "obase=16; ibase=16; $branch_line_number + 1" | bc -l)
sum=$(printf "%03x" $val)
echo "check 6 val = $val : sum = $sum"
```

Resulting in :

```
line 4: printf: 1B: invalid number check 6 val = 1B : sum = 001
```

I have also tried :

```
branch_line_number=01A
val=$(echo "obase=16; ibase=16; $branch_line_number + 1" | bc -l)
sum=$(printf "%05s" $val)
echo "check 6 val = $val : sum = $sum"
```

Resulting in :

```
check 6 val = 1B : sum =    1B
```

(Note: There are 3 spaces where there should be a zeros in "sum")

What's weird is I have tried the following script :

```
branch_line_number=016
val=$(echo "obase=16; ibase=16; $branch_line_number + 1" | bc -l)
sum=$(printf "%05d" $val)
echo "check 6 val = $val : sum = $sum"
```

and I get this result :

```
check 6 val = 17 : sum = 00017
```

I am just trying to do it for hexadecimal numbers. I am very confused as to why no leading zeros are being printed to the terminal. From my research, it looks like I have the right code, just not the correct output.

Comment: `printf '%05X\n' '0x1B'` prints `0001B`, `printf '%05X\n' "$((0x1B + 0x1))"` gives `0001C`, and so on

Comment: Please use multi-line code segments instead of using single-line code segments over and over. This not only formats better / more compactly, it also gives you color syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use `bc` to compute with bases different than 10 in bash. Use the prefix `base#` before your number.

```bash
branch_line_number=01A
printf -v sum "%5X" $(( 16#$branch_line_number + 1 ))
echo "sum = $sum"
```

Result

```
sum = 1B
```

### Update

You could use `%05X` formatter instead of `%5X` to obtain this result:

```
sum = 0001B
```

### Note

The syntax `printf -v var_name "format" ...` is really faster and pretty than `var_name=$(printf "format" ...)`. Use this second form only if your shell or OS does not support `printf` with `-v` option.

In order to use `-v` option, you need to use bash. Check your `printf` version with:

```bash
> type printf
printf is a shell builtin
```

You must use bash bultin function. Not `/usr/bin/printf` command

Comment: pretty `printf -v var smth` could complain `printf: Illegal option -v`, maybe some extra notes need to add

Comment: Which bash version do you use? What is the result of `type printf`?

Comment: lets say it's /usr/bin/printf, printf(1)

Comment: Which bash version do you use? (`bash --version` or `echo $BASH_VERSION`). Do you really use bash ?

Comment: Sometimes, not too often. I see the new update about "you _must_ use bash", now that explains a bit better the scopes

Comment: You have tagged your request with `bash` tag. So, my response is for bash

Comment: not me, but yes I agree, it's a reasonable notice, despite that it's easy to do in posix way

Answer (score 0):

> why no leading zeros are being printed to the terminal

```
printf "%05s"
```

`0` only works with integers and floating points for padding. You can't expect it to work with `s`. The `printf` you are using ignores `0` with `s`, and has every right to do so.

Let's throw a reference, from https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf :

> 0 : for integer and floating point number conversions, leading zeros are used to pad the field instead of space characters. For integer numbers it is ignored if the precision is explicitly specified. For other conversions using this flag results in undefined behavior. It is ignored if - flag is present.